# VMWare Fusion 4 - Add batch file to Application Menu

Tags: macos, mac, vmware-fusion

I'm in the process of switching from Full Screen mode to Unity mode.  The last item I need is a way to easily execute a windows batch file that I've stored on my windows desktop.

Ideally I'd like to add it to the Applications Menu so I can access it from the icon at the top of my mac screen.  But when I go to the VM's Settings -> Applications Menu and then click the + there is a select list of items that I can add to the list.

Is there a way to add to this list so I can add my batch file to the Application Menu?  Or is there an easier method to accomplish this goal?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Turn off Unity, open the **Start** menu and drop a shortcut to the batch file in the **All Programs** menu. Then turn Unity back on. Your batch script should now be available to use in VMWare Unity.

Comment: I'm looking for how to put the program into the 'quick launch' section of the application menu. I've been able to add to the windows start menu with no problems. The area I'm looking for is within the Applications Menu Settings -> Add items to the applications menu.